# Playbook is unable to create VM running into fatal error

Tags: ansible

We have a playbook which create the VM. First time when I ran the infrastructure pipeline VM is created.
After making some "sku" related changes in playbook and trying to run the pipeline again, getting below error.

```
2020-11-09T09:42:37.7488228Z TASK [ansible-role-adfv2-shir : Install Java Runtime Environment] **************
2020-11-09T09:42:37.7489504Z task path: /opt/ansible-roles/cloud/2020.10-212/ansible-role-adfv2-shir/tasks/install.yml:24
2020-11-09T09:42:37.7491381Z Monday 09 November 2020  04:42:37 -0500 (0:00:31.732)       0:12:49.681 ******* 
2020-11-09T09:42:37.8258708Z Using module file /home/cvx_admin_user/.ansible-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_package.ps1
2020-11-09T09:42:37.8261046Z <10.71.116.128> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: cvx_admin_user on PORT 5986 TO 10.71.116.128
2020-11-09T09:42:37.8261724Z checking if winrm_host 10.71.116.128 is an IPv6 address
2020-11-09T09:42:37.8262337Z <10.71.116.128> WINRM CONNECT: transport=ssl endpoint=https://10.71.116.128:5986/wsman
2020-11-09T09:42:37.9552112Z <10.71.116.128> WINRM OPEN SHELL: 6450AAB3-A367-49DA-B034-B197FC2A464D
2020-11-09T09:42:37.9555186Z EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
2020-11-09T09:42:37.9558598Z <10.71.116.128> WINRM EXEC 'PowerShell' ['-NoProfile', '-NonInteractive', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-']
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3305027Z <10.71.116.128> WINRM RESULT u'<Response code 0, out "{"stdout":"","rc":16", err "">'
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3361619Z <10.71.116.128> WINRM CLOSE SHELL: 6450AAB3-A367-49DA-B034-B197FC2A464D
**2020-11-09T09:43:15.3500563Z fatal: [corest-tsir00]: FAILED! => {
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3530075Z     "changed": false, 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3560075Z     "exit_code": 1618, 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3560924Z     "msg": "unexpected rc from install  C:\\ExeSources\\jre8u191windowsx64.exe: see rc, stdout and stderr for more details", 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3561602Z     "rc": 1618, 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3562066Z     "reboot_required": false, 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3562571Z     "restart_required": false, 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3563039Z     "stderr": "", 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3563488Z     "stderr_lines": [], 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3563938Z     "stdout": "", 
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3564377Z     "stdout_lines": []
2020-11-09T09:43:15.3564820Z }**
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Please help me out with this error.
Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, we need to see the play that's giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your return code for `jre8u191windowsx64.exe` is `1618`, which means `ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING`. The [MSI error code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/error-codes) tells us that:

> Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install.

Comment: Ok this issue is due to "Another installation is already in progress." 
How to fix it in playbook?

Comment: I cannot answer this, as you did not provide any playbook or any information about that your playbook does. This is likely a new question, but more suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) than StackOverflow.

Comment: I deleted all the resources and ran the pipeline it is succeeded.